# compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7' not resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

this code of my build.gradle(moudule app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hn.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and this is my sdk tools.
[image: and this is my sdk tools]

I try `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'`
and `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'`
and `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.+'`
but not working. and error is
`Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1`
who I solve this problem?

When I use `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7`
this error done: **install artifact and sync project**

Comment: try mine     compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Comment: Compile that but this error is done: 'Install Repository and sync project'

Answer (score 0):

go to file -> setting -> sdk manager -> sdk tools -> then install google repository

[image]